# Apache Ant - error: package javax.servlet does not exist

Tags: java, servlets, ant, build

I am currently trying to build a Java Project with an Apache Ant Build Server inside an TFS. I did not create the Projects, just trying to setup the Build Server now.

I get multiple errors, all related to javax.servlet missing:

1. error: package javax.servlet does not exist [javac] import
   javax.servlet.ServletException
2. error: package javax.servlet.http
   does not exist [javac] import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet

etc...

The Project was made with Netbeans and is quiet big, so manual change to Maven was not an option for me and I decided to use Apache Ant.

I had multiple problems with missing jar's, but i could fix them through the -lib command when start the building, like adding

```
-Dlibs.CopyLibs.classpath=C:\Agent\..\lib\org-netbeans-modules-java-j2seproject-copylibstask.jar
```

Which works fine.

What I tried with help from existing threads here and google.

1. I tried the -lib command thing with the servlet-api.jar and tried multiple    versions. In Netbeans itself occurs no error with the servlet, because I can manually set it in the properties.
2. I ran ant -diagnostics and put the .jar file manually in the folder where Ant is looking for .jar files.
3. set CLASSPATH system environment variable to tomcat folder and the servlet-api.jar.
4. Specify a classpath in the build.xml and in the targets.
5. Add the .class files manually into the build folder...reduces error messages but still can't find some classes, even if they are in the folder, like the javax.servlet.servletexception.

Comment: Did you restart the build agent after changing the system level environment variables?

Comment: Yes I did, did not help